# Array contents not displaying well, when placed between certain lines of the code

Tags: php, mysql, html, arrays

Whenever I move the codeblock that generates courses with a grade of "F", it does not not echo out the courses that meets the criteria. But when I move it to beginning of the main div header of the script it displays well.. What could the problem be? I actually want it to be at the end of the script for the sake of printing out. I've also checked the source code and the parameters I was looking for wasn't there.

[Pastebin of full code](http://www.pastebin.com/EkXv3J3s)

```
echo "<table bgcolor = red >";

echo "<tr align= \"center\">"; 

$carry_over = array(); 

$score_count = mysql_numrows($query8);

echo "<th>"."Failed Courses : "."</th>";

if($score_count !== 0){

   while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query8)) { 

      echo"<td>". $row8['course_code']."</td>;
   }

}         

echo "</tr>\n"; 

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this?

```
echo "<th>"."Failed Courses : "."</th>";
```

do

```
echo "<th>"."Failed Courses : </th>";
```

and also before you do a while loop try to see what your results looks like.

`$row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query8)`

then `print_r($row8);`

post your results.

Also the table structure should be

```
<table>
    <th></th>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are inconsistencies between your provided example here and the pastebin code you linked to. Which version are you using?

If it's the pastebin version you may be having issues with this line:

```
echo "<th>"."Failed Courses";
```

You are missing the `</th>` tag which could be messing with your output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is going to be a long bit of code so I'm posting it here, I don't intend for this to be an answer to your problem as I can't get it to do what you're saying.

PHP allows for information to be set outside of the PHP tags, and when that happens it is treated as regular HTML.

E.G.

```
<?php

  If(2==2){
   ?><b>HELLO!</b><?php
  }

?>
```

And

```
<?php

  if(2==2){
   echo "<b>HELLO!</b>";
  }
?>
```

Will both result in `<b>HELLO!</b>` to be output to the screen. This is useful for things that might require a lot of HTML in more than one block, as well as HTML that may require extensive style definitions or other places where double quotes will be needed, for example

`<div id="list_row[$i]" class="something something2 something3">` would have to be escaped as

`echo <div id=\"list_row[$i]\" class=\"something something2 something3\">` whereas it could just be put more or less intact in php using the above mentioned fact. Now, there would still need to be an `echo` statement for the $i portion, as I don't think PHP processes the text, but I've never tried it so I can't be sure.

As for your HTML,
`<th>` tags are meant to be a header, aka in the top part of a table. `<td>` are meant to be table-data cells.

Seems like you're making a lot of unnecessary calls to the same MySQL tables, and I'm hoping I can condense it down a bit.